# Is $\left\{ u\in H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\left|\,a<u\left(x\right) <b\:\text{a.e.}\right.\right\}$ open in $H^1(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega$ bounded, open, connected and Lip. domain.Let positive constants $a,b$ such that $a<b$.
Is $A = \left\{ u\in H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\left|\,a<u\left(x\right)
<b\:\text{a.e.}\right.\right\}$  open in $H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$?

Note that:

1. $\left\{ u\in H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\left|\,b\leq u\left(x\right)\:\text{a.e.}\right.\right\}$  and $\left\{ u\in H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\left|\,u\left(x\right)\leq a\:\text{a.e.}\right.\right\}$  are closed sets in $H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$: Convergence in $H^1(\Omega)$ implies convergence in $L^2(\Omega)$....Then, the complement,$A$, is open.
2. If $A$ is open, for all $u\in A$ there is $r$ such $B_{r}\left(u\right)\subset A$. Let $v\in H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\backslash L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$. Then, $u+tv\in B_{r}\left(u\right)$ for small $t$. As $A\subset L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$, $u$ and $u+tv\in L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$, then $v\in L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$. $(\rightarrow\leftarrow)$

I don't know which, 1 or 2, is wrong.

Comment: Here there is something about the topology you are looking: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584519/what-is-the-h-01-omega-topology/1584766#1584766

Answer (score 1):

The complement of 
$$
\{ u\in H^1: \ b\le u(x) \ a.e.\}
$$
is *not* equal to
$$
\{ u\in H^1: \ b> u(x) \ a.e.\}.
$$
So (2) is right, (1) is wrong.

Comment: What is the complement?

Comment: What is the negation of the statement: the real numbers $a$ and $b$ are both positive?

Comment: The complement is $\left\{ u\in H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\left|\:\mu\left(\left\{ x\left|b>u\left(x\right)\right.\right\} \right)>0\right.\right\} $. Thanks @daw!